# Как сделать проверку есть ли в бд введённые данные или нет

Tags: python, sqlite3

sql3 = ("""SELECT password FROM inut_regist WHERE password =(?)""")
cursor.execute(sql3, [user_password])

```
    sql4 = ('''SELECT login FROM inut_regist WHERE login =(?)''')
    cursor.execute(sql4, [user_login])
    
    if  :
        self.label.setText('Ошибка авторизации!')
    else:
        self.label.setText('Успешная авторизация!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = cursor.execute("SELECT login, password FROM inut_regist WHERE login = ? AND password = ?", (user_login, user_password)).fetchone()

if len(data) > 0:
    # True
else:
    # False
```

Проверить наличие данных можно таким образом.

Comment: Я не правильно вопрос поставил . Как именно соотнести то что вписал пользователь с тем что есть в таблице ? То есть он вписал пароль и логин и они сохранились и потом что бы снова войти  пользователю надо вписать тот же пароль и логин как это проверить  . Можете пожалуйста пдсказать ? Я знаю только что это через WERE  надо делать

Comment: @ВишнуджанВайнштэйн, в моем ответе содержится проверка пользователя по логину и паролю. Запрос с двумя параметрами login и password. Данные должны совпасть иначе вернется 0 строк и это будет False.

Comment: Простите я немного по началу не понял , спасибо

Comment: @ВишнуджанВайнштэйн, рад был помочь.